# numpy.float64' object is not iterable -- TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I cant understand why this error occurring!! What is the better solution for changing this error?? Can anyone please explain why it is occuring

```
the error is as follows: 
Train...
(0, 0)
start
2020-04-11 13:55:01.049361: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Test1...
integeroverflow_1_.pkl
api_1_.pkl
pointersuse_5_.pkl
pointersuse_4_.pkl
pointersuse_3_.pkl
pointersuse_0_.pkl
arraysuse_1_.pkl
integeroverflow_0_.pkl
api_3_.pkl
pointersuse_2_.pkl
arraysuse_0_.pkl
api_2_.pkl
api_0_.pkl
pointersuse_1_.pkl
(8492, 8492, 8492)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 220, in <module>
    main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
  File "bgru.py", line 126, in main
    score, TP, FP, FN, precision, recall, f_score= result[0]
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

The Part of code where the error is getting is shown below:

```
bin_labels = []
    for label in labels:
        bin_labels.append(multi_labels_to_two(label))
    labels = bin_labels

    batch_size = 1
    test_generator = generator_of_data(dataset, labels, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim)
    all_test_samples = len(dataset)
    steps_epoch = int(math.ceil(all_test_samples / batch_size))

    t1 = time.time()
    result = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=steps_epoch)
    t2 = time.time()
    test_time = t2 - t1
    score, TP, FP, FN, precision, recall, f_score= result[0]
```

The full code is in https://github.com/SySeVR/SySeVR/blob/master/Implementation/model/bgru.py

```
from keras.callbacks import ProgbarLogger
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adagrad, Adam, Adadelta
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers.core import Masking, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM,GRU
from preprocess_dl_Input_version5 import *
from keras.layers.wrappers import Bidirectional
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pickle
import random
import time
import math
import os

RANDOMSEED = 2018  # for reproducibility
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

from keras import backend as K

def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

def build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
    print('Build model...')
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(maxlen, vector_dim)))

    for i in range(1, layers):
        model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True)))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid')))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['accuracy', 'mae', recall_m, precision_m, f1_m])

    model.summary()

    return model


def main(traindataSet_path, testdataSet_path, realtestpath, weightpath, resultpath, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
    print("Loading data...")

    model = build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout)

    #model.load_weights(weightpath)  #load weights of trained model

    print("Train...")
    dataset = []
    labels = []
    testcases = []
    for filename in os.listdir(traindataSet_path):
        if(filename.endswith(".pkl") is True):
            continue
        print(filename)
        f = open(os.path.join(traindataSet_path, filename),"rb")
        dataset_file,labels_file,funcs_file,filenames_file,testcases_file = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        dataset += dataset_file
        labels += labels_file           
    print(len(dataset), len(labels))

    bin_labels = []
    for label in labels:
        bin_labels.append(multi_labels_to_two(label))
    labels = bin_labels

    np.random.seed(RANDOMSEED)
    np.random.shuffle(dataset)
    np.random.seed(RANDOMSEED)
    np.random.shuffle(labels)

    train_generator = generator_of_data(dataset, labels, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim)    
    all_train_samples = len(dataset)
    steps_epoch = int(all_train_samples / batch_size)
    print("start")
    t1 = time.time()
    model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_epoch, epochs=10, verbose=0)
    t2 = time.time()
    train_time = t2 - t1

    model.save_weights(weightpath)

    #model.load_weights(weightpath)
    print("Test1...")
    dataset = []
    labels = []
    testcases = []
    filenames = []
    funcs = []
    for filename in os.listdir(traindataSet_path):
        if(filename.endswith(".pkl") is False):
           continue
        print(filename)
        f = open(os.path.join(traindataSet_path, filename),"rb")
        datasetfile,labelsfile,funcsfiles,filenamesfile,testcasesfile = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        dataset += datasetfile
        labels += labelsfile
        testcases += testcasesfile
        funcs += funcsfiles
        filenames += filenamesfile
    print(len(dataset), len(labels), len(testcases))

    bin_labels = []
    for label in labels:
        bin_labels.append(multi_labels_to_two(label))
    labels = bin_labels

    batch_size = 1
    test_generator = generator_of_data(dataset, labels, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim)
    all_test_samples = len(dataset)
    steps_epoch = int(math.ceil(all_test_samples / batch_size))

    t1 = time.time()
    result = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=steps_epoch)
    t2 = time.time()
    test_time = t2 - t1
    score, TP, FP, FN, precision, recall, f_score= result[0]
    f = open("TP_index_blstm.pkl",'wb')
    pickle.dump(result[1], f)
    f.close()

    f_TP = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/TP_filenames.txt","ab+")
    for i in range(len(result[1])):
       TP_index = result[1][i]
       f_TP.write(str(filenames[TP_index])+'\n')

    f_FP = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/FP_filenames.txt","ab+")
    for j in range(len(result[2])):
       FP_index = result[2][j]
       f_FP.write(str(filenames[FP_index])+'\n')

    f_FN = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/FN_filenames.txt","a+")
    for k in range(len(result[3])):
       FN_index = result[3][k]
       f_FN.write(str(filenames[FN_index])+'\n')

    TN = all_test_samples - TP - FP - FN
    fwrite = open(resultpath, 'a')
    fwrite.write('cdg_ddg: ' + ' ' + str(all_test_samples) + '\n')
    fwrite.write("TP:" + str(TP) + ' FP:' + str(FP) + ' FN:' + str(FN) + ' TN:' + str(TN) +'\n')
    FPR = float(FP) / (FP + TN)
    fwrite.write('FPR: ' + str(FPR) + '\n')
    FNR = float(FN) / (TP + FN)
    fwrite.write('FNR: ' + str(FNR) + '\n')
    Accuracy = float(TP + TN) / (all_test_samples)
    fwrite.write('Accuracy: ' + str(Accuracy) + '\n')
    precision = float(TP) / (TP + FP)
    fwrite.write('precision: ' + str(precision) + '\n')
    recall = float(TP) / (TP + FN)
    fwrite.write('recall: ' + str(recall) + '\n')
    f_score = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    fwrite.write('fbeta_score: ' + str(f_score) + '\n')
    fwrite.write('train_time:' + str(train_time) +'  ' + 'test_time:' + str(test_time) + '\n')
    fwrite.write('--------------------\n')
    fwrite.close()

    dict_testcase2func = {}
    for i in testcases:
        if not i in dict_testcase2func:
            dict_testcase2func[i] = {}
    TP_indexs = result[1]
    for i in TP_indexs:
        if funcs[i] == []:
            continue
        for func in funcs[i]:
            if func in dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]].keys():
                dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]][func].append("TP")
            else:
                dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]][func] = ["TP"]
    FP_indexs = result[1]
    for i in FP_indexs:
        if funcs[i] == []:
            continue
        for func in funcs[i]:
            if func in dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]].keys():
                dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]][func].append("FP")
            else:
                dict_testcase2func[testcases[i]][func] = ["FP"]
    f = open(resultpath+"_dict_testcase2func.pkl",'wb')
    pickle.dump(dict_testcase2func, f)
    f.close()

def testrealdata(realtestpath, weightpath, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
    model = build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout)
    model.load_weights(weightpath)

    print("Loading data...")
    for filename in os.listdir(realtestpath):
        print(filename)
        f = open(realtestpath+filename, "rb")
        realdata = pickle.load(f,encoding="latin1")
        f.close()

        labels = model.predict(x = realdata[0],batch_size = 1)
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            if labels[i][0] >= 0.5:
                print(realdata[1][i])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    batchSize = 32
    vectorDim = 40
    maxLen = 500
    layers = 2
    dropout = 0.2
    traindataSetPath = "./dl_input_shuffle/cdg_ddg/train/"
    testdataSetPath = "./dl_input_shuffle/cdg_ddg/test/"
    realtestdataSetPath = "data/"
    weightPath = './model/BRGU'
    resultPath = "./result/BGRU/BGRU"
    main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
    #testrealdata(realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
```

I have uploaded the full code that i was running.Please look upon it!!

Comment: What metrics are defined for your model? Seems only loss was defined, so evaluate_generator returns only one number

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro metrics=['accuracy', 'mae']

Comment: Maybe then include full code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i just edited my post, so you can have a look on full code using that link

Comment: This doesn't seem to be your code (metrics are different), if you modified that code then any change would explain the problem

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Actuallly that mterics given in that code i,e TP_count, FP_count like that its gives error for me, so i changed my metrics as 'accuracy' and 'mae'

Comment: Yes, that's my point, you modified the code, so this is not the code you are actually running. Any detail you think it is irrelevant might be actually relevant. Include your actual code in the question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro sir, i have uploaded the full code, you can look on it!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unpack a numpy float. Try this and you will get the same error:

```
v1, v2 = np.float64(1.3)  # numpy.float64 object, cannot be unpacked because it is not an iterable
```

result[0] is a numpy float, just as np.float64.
I'm not sure what `results` holds, but removing the `[0]` index might fix your problem, if the data you want is in the array `result`